# How to calculate time diffrence in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am storing the user activity in the table by start and end time , now i want to calculate how much overall time a user spends under each subject.

Below given is my table structure

[image: Table structure]

I tried using some query but i didnt get the output as i required .How can I calculate it ? Any help is appreciable.

This is the code that i tried

```
SELECT MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMEDIFF(TIME(end_time), TIME(start_time))))) AS prep_time FROM prep_learn_log WHERE user_id = '1' GROUP BY subject_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`TIMESTAMPDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to get the difference in minutes directly:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, end_time)) AS prep_time
FROM prep_learn_log 
WHERE user_id = '1' 
GROUP BY subject_id
```